# I need help with a limit proof

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I tried to proof this limit but when i get epsilon i can't narrow it because there's a factorization something unusual. The limit that i need to proof is:
$\lim_{z\to1}\frac{{z^2 -1}}{z-1} = 2$
I would appreciate if somebody can help me with this proof. Thank you.

Comment: Start by factorising $z^2-1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $z\ne1$, $\displaystyle\left|\frac{z^2-1}{z-1}-2\right|=\left|z-1\right|$. If $z\to1$, the RHS converges to zero. QED.

Comment: What's wrong with simply simplifying $\frac{z^2-1}{z-1}$ to $z+1$?

Comment: @barakmanos Where did I say it was?

Comment: Sorry, can you please rephrase that question?

Comment: @barakmanos Where did I say it was wrong to "simply simplify" (nice...) etc.? Answer: I did not.

Comment: If I just may add, the proof above looks a bit over complicated. OP asks to prove convergence to $2$, you're proving convergence to $0$. OP asks for the limit of $\frac{z^2-1}{z-1}$, you're explaining the limit of $|\frac{z^2-1}{z-1}-2|$.

Comment: So if possible cancel that terms in te proof? Because if i do that so delta will be equal to epsilon.

Comment: I need to know the epsilon-delta proof with details is if possible thank you.

Comment: egarro: Let $f$ denote the function of interest. Indeed, choosing $\delta=\varepsilon$ yields $$|z-1|\leqslant\delta,z\ne1\implies\left|f(z)-2\right|\leqslant\varepsilon.$$ Note that the condition $z\ne1$ is necessary because $f$ is not defined at $1$.

Comment: So i need to narrow epsilon with 1/2 right, and then take the minimum of that?

Comment: @barakmanos The *easiest* and *simplest* way I know to show that $f(z)\to2$ is to show that $|f(z)-2|\to0$. Does your comment suggest that there exists some easier and/or simpler approaches than this one?

Comment: egarro ?? Narrow epsilon? Take the minimum? Sorry but what are you talking about? These are not in my proof anyway.

Comment: Well, in my opinion, explaining the limit of $z+1$ (as $z$ approaches $1$) is simpler and easier. That's why I asked what was wrong with it.

Comment: I think the OP means to take $\delta =\min\left\{\frac 1 2 ,\varepsilon\right\}$.

Comment: @GitGud Ah OK, thanks. Then, no, the minimum is not necessary and the choice $\delta=\varepsilon$ is all right.

Comment: Well i am not an english speaker and that terms are which i use on my class of calculus, i just translate it from spanish to english, sorry. For example if the proof of a limit gets epsilon/absolute value, then you narrow the absolute value, making delta less or equal to something, with the goal of get an appropriate choose of delta. :) Do you get it? Yes is exactly as Git Gud say.

Comment: @barakmanos Here is a thought experiment: let us wonder why this homework was given to the OP. My guess is that the reason was to emphasize the importance of the domain of definition of functions when considering limits. Here, the function $f$ is **not** $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, $z\mapsto z+1$ hence every solution which passes over this technicality is, IMHO, misleading.

Comment: @barakmanos Your method of proof is something that would only come up after you proved some things with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ and not only does the OP want an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof, this answer directly hints at how to get one due the equality stated in it.

Comment: What you recommend me do?

Comment: Actually, my interpretation of this "tricky homework assignment" is much simpler than yours: You can't set $z=1$ on a fraction with the denominator being $z-1$... But at this point I guess that it's a manner of subjective interpretation, right?

Comment: Yes you have right, but this is a limit, it doesn't matter if z= ->1 because it never get the value 1, it is just an approximation.

Comment: @barakmanos You seem to like to declare unilaterally that your point of view or your (unspecified) own approaches would be "simpler". This is a pleasure I can understand, but here is my advice: do not overdo it... :-)

Comment: egarro: If you got this point, everything is fine (although the fact that you use he term "an approximation", quite unrelated, worries me slightly in this respect...).

Comment: Well excuse if the terms that i use are wrong, but thats why i learn on my class. I just need an answer or a guide for this problem, i really need to. Please i just need help. I want to know more math and things like this are very important for me because i want to learn more. :)

Comment: @Did I understand your answer thanks a lot! I take time to understand but I understood. Now everything is clearer :)

Comment: Please no excuse for the time you took--on the contrary!

Answer (score 1):

$$\large z^2-1=(z-1)(z+1)$$
$$f(z)=\frac{z^2-1}{z-1}=\begin{cases}\begin{align}z+1\quad z\ne1\\\text{undefined}\quad z=1\end{align}\end{cases}$$
For every $\epsilon>0$, there is some number $\delta>0$ such that:
$$|f(z)-2|<\epsilon\qquad\text{whenever}\qquad 0<|z-1|<\delta$$
$\left(\text{actually }\delta(\epsilon)=\epsilon\right)$

which is equivalent saying:
$$\lim_{z\to1}f(z)=2$$

Comment: Sorry but to consider some $\varepsilon(\delta)$ reflects a deep misconception about the notion of limit.

Comment: @Did what's wrong with it, seems correct to me?

Comment: $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$, not vice versa.

Comment: @Did  Oh!, a typo